# Count Form Values Equal to 0 with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

```
$("#scorecard").change(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $("#scorecard :checked").each(

    function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).val())
    });
    $("#score").val(total);
}).change();
```

This function sums the radio checked values in a html form in real-time. 
http://jsfiddle.net/hireconor/DDfbf/

How can I modify it, so it will **count** the checked radio values that are equal to 0? So if checked value is 0 then equals 1, anything else = 0 and sum then minus it by 18 displaying it in the text box with the id="score".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat non-obvious approach:

```
var total = $('#scorecard :checked').filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() === '0';
}).length;
```

Here's an updated [jsfiddle of it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/DDfbf/2/).

---

Edit: I wasn't sure exactly how to interpret `minus it by 18`... is that `18 - total` or `total - 18`? Anyway, here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DDfbf/4/) showing the former.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick and added 18 to '$("#played").val(18 - total);'.

Comment: Can I piggy back off that and ask how to display (total score - par score). But it's tricky because if a hole hasn't been played the par should not be subtracted from current score. Here's what I've tried so far: http://jsfiddle.net/hireconor/DDfbf/11/

Answer (score 0):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DDfbf/3/

```
$("#scorecard").change(function() {
    var total = 0;
    var checkedTotal = 0;

    $("#scorecard :checked").each(

    function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).val())
        if (this.value == 0) {
            checkedTotal++;
        }
    });
    $("#score").val(total);
    console.log(checkedTotal);
}).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/kVe8a/)

```
 $("#scorecard").change(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $("#scorecard :checked").each(

    function() {
        var valu = parseInt($(this).val());
        if(valu === 0){
          total += 1;
        }
        else{
        total += valu;
        }
    });
    $("#score").val(18-total);
}).change();
```